# Make dojo.dnd.Source out of dragged/copied item

Tags: javascript, dojo, drag-and-drop

I have setup a small interface with a left panel(source) and a right panel(source & target).

Dragging/copying from the left panel to the right panel works and a new div is created when dropped.

I now want to be able to drop items into the new div, i.e. the new div should also be a source.

However I am not sure how to do this, can you help?

HTML

```
<div id="left-panel"> 
    <div class="dojoDndItem">Div</div>
</div>

<div id="right-panel">
</div>
```

JS

```
//This is a creator to be run when an item is dropped onto the right panel

function myCreator(item, hint) {
if (item == 'Div') {
var myNode = dojo.create('div');
}

//This is how I create the sources

var leftPanel = new Source("left-panel", { copyOnly:true });

var rightPanel = new Source("right-panel", { accept:[ "div", "button", "image" ], creator:myCreator });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

see http://jsfiddle.net/n8UxB/

```
<div id="left-panel" class="container"> 
    <div class="dojoDndItem" dndType="foo">Div</div>
    <div class="dojoDndItem" dndType="foo">Div2</div>
</div>
```

you don't need the creator function.  and accept is for dndType DOM attributes.